# REST servie with client to upload file

Tags: java, rest, file-upload

I building a REST service that would upload a WAR file on some machine(remote or local) with the following code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataContentDisposition;
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataParam;

@Path("/upload")
public class FileUpload {
    @POST
    @Path("/pdf")
    @Consumes({MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA})
    public Response uploadPdfFile(  @FormDataParam("file") InputStream fileInputStream,
                                    @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileMetaData) throws Exception
    {
        String UPLOAD_PATH = "D:/";
        try
        {
            int read = 0;
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(UPLOAD_PATH + fileMetaData.getFileName()));
            while ((read = fileInputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) 
            {
                out.write(bytes, 0, read);
            }
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) 
        {
            throw new WebApplicationException("Error while uploading file. Please try again !!");
        }
        return Response.ok("Data uploaded successfully !!").build();
    }

}
```

And the client java code is as follows:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Entity;
import javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataMultiPart;
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartFeature;
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.file.FileDataBodyPart;

public class FileUploadClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
    {
        final Client client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder().register(MultiPartFeature.class).build();

        final FileDataBodyPart filePart = new FileDataBodyPart("file", new File("C:/Users/Jainesh_Trivedi/Desktop/WAR/AutohostDemo1_1145.war"));
        FormDataMultiPart formDataMultiPart = new FormDataMultiPart();
        final FormDataMultiPart multipart = (FormDataMultiPart) formDataMultiPart.field("foo", "bar").bodyPart(filePart);

        final WebTarget target = client.target("http://localhost:10001/JerseyFileUpload/rest/upload/pdf");
        final Response response = target.request().post(Entity.entity(multipart, multipart.getMediaType()));

        //Use response object to verify upload success

        formDataMultiPart.close();
        multipart.close();
    }


}
```

Kindly help me with this as I'm getting the following error:

```
    Exception in thread "main" javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: java.io.IOException: Error writing to server
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.HttpUrlConnector.apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:229)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.invoke(ClientRuntime.java:246)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$1.call(JerseyInvocation.java:667)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$1.call(JerseyInvocation.java:664)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:228)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:424)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:664)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:424)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.post(JerseyInvocation.java:333)
    at com.fileupload.rest.FileUploadClient.main(FileUploadClient.java:27)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error writing to server
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.writeRequests(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.writeRequests(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.HttpUrlConnector._apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:321)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.HttpUrlConnector.apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:227)
    ... 11 more
```